# How to add/remove a shape with a key press in Processing?

Tags: processing, ellipse

I want to add/remove an ellipse using a press of a button in Processing. I use void keyPressed() and void keyReleased() for the keys. But how can I use if statements to add/remove an ellipse?

Now that i can add more , and remove some ellipses. For example, if i have one i can press a button then have one more. Or press a button to remove one. But now I would like to move those ellipses (max 4) using different key sets for each of them. How can i do that?

Answer (score 2):

What you need to do is have a boolean to be read whenever the ellipse is to be drawn. If that is true draw it, if it not don't! THe keypress should just switch that boolean. Like this:

```
boolean iShouldDrawTheEllipse = true;
void draw() {
  background(0);
  if(iShouldDrawTheEllipse) ellipse(50,50,10,10);
}
void keyPressed() {
  iShouldDrawTheEllipse = !iShouldDrawTheEllipse;
}
```

Comment: Now that i can add more , and remove some ellipses. For example, if i have one i can press a button then have one more. Or press a button to remove one. But now I would like to move those ellipses (max 4) using different key sets for each of them. How can i do that?

Comment: Then please make that into a different question and accept this one if it answered your first!

Answer (score 0):

You can use some `boolean`s to determinate which ellipse you have to print and which not.

E.G.

```
void keyPressed(){
  switch(keyCode){
    case 'z':
      drawingFirstEllipse = !drawingFirstEllipse;
      break;
    case 'x':
      drawingSecondEllipse = !drawingSecondEllipse;
    break;
    case 'c':
      drawingThirdEllipse = !drawingThirdEllipse;
    break;
    case 'v':
      drawingFourthEllipse = !drawingFourthEllipse;
    break;
  }
}
```

Then in your `void draw(void)` method you can easily draw the ellipses:

```
void draw(){
  background(0);
  if(drawingFirstEllipse) ellipse(50, 50, 10, 10);
  if(drawingSecondEllipse) ellipse(50, 50, 70, 10);
  if(drawingThirdEllipse) ellipse(50, 50, 130, 10);
  if(drawingFourthEllipse) ellipse(50, 50, 190, 10);
}
```

I hope I helped [;